# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'weight'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

```
class Apple:
    def __init__( self,w,c):
        self.weight=w
        self.color=c
        print("utworzono!")



ap1=(280,"red")
print(ap1)
print(ap1.weight)
```

I don't know what I do wrong. Every thing what I write here is from book.

Comment: You actually did `api1 = (280, "red")` instead of `api1 = Apple(280, "red")`. You can read more about [tuples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm).

Answer (score 4):

`ap1` is not an instance of an `Apple`, it's just a plain old tuple. You need to invoke `Apple`'s construtor explicitly:

```
ap1 = Apple(280, "red")
```